# Making Two Objects EXACTLY Flush

Tags: mesh, objects, transforms, faces, snapping

Note the following image:
[image]

I am trying to align the object on the left and the one on the right, so that they are EXACTLY flush to each other and there is not flickering overlap.

What is the best way to do this? I tried zooming way in orthographically and moving the left one slowly, but it still overlapped slightly.

Is there an easy way to do this? Alternatively, is there a way to make the right object impassable, so that the left object simply stops at the edge of the mess?

Thanks!

Comment: Related: http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/539/snap-object-on-top-of-surface-of-other-object

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The "flickering overlap" (known as z-fighting) isn't really avoidable. Due to things like floating point rounding errors, there is no such thing as exactly flush in computer graphics. If two polygons are coplanar enough, you start getting calculations that sometimes round off with polygon A being on top, and some round off with polygon B on top. Hence, z-fighting. In most cases, you are much better off having either a small gap or subtly intersecting the two objects, depending on your needs.

That said, you can use face snapping to get one object "flush" with another object: [Snap object on top of surface of other object](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/539/snap-object-on-top-of-surface-of-other-object)

But again, due to precision limitations, "flush" is ill-defined and hovering or intersecting the two surfaces is often preferable so one is strictly defined as being on top of the other.