# map editor blender game engine

Tags: game-engine

i want to create **map editor** inside **blender game engine**, i know *python*,

I created game assets and i want to put them on terrain i created before, but the question is how...

How to make object add on the surface of terrain not in air

Comment: Please clarify more. Also, your question is doubled.

Comment: I strongly suggest to make "How to make object add on the surface of terrain not in air" as question. The current one "map editor blender game engine" is not a question and would be too broad. -- please rephrase

Comment: @Bug Fernandez check Ketsji Game Engine Fork of UPBG, find it on github

Comment: If you have time to exchange project knowledge, we contact outside of here

Comment: @user62213 yes we can

Answer (score 0):

i would split the map editor up in two parts, Terrain editor and Prod editor.

For the Terrain i would do it with textures maps, so when you edit the terrain you are painting on Bump,Normal,Spec,Diff and so on.

For the prod you need to make a inventory like menu, and then Edit object "add/remove" in a RTS like way.

This might be a quite big project, but if you split up the problems in smaller pieces i think it can be done, and it will make it way more convenient for other ppl to help you with it.

Comment: I understand the terrain editor part but will you please elaborate the Prod editor part in detail.

Comment: I just ment it as a way to place objects from a list of assets, but... The game engine in blende have been discontinued by the blender team

Comment: @BugFernandez you want the editor inside or outside the game, more specific, you want this to create terrains and assets within the game, or to create your assets for your development, I still do not achieve it, I have some attempts to do it within the game but there are things that I do not know how to solve them

Answer (score 0):

You would be better off forgetting the game engine part of it, unless you plan on sticking with 2.79 for a while. Game engine has been removed from future versions. 
Look at the current Terrain editor addon, [ANT Landscape](https://en.blender.org/index.php/Extensions:2.6/Py/Scripts/Add_Mesh/ANT_Landscape), and see how it works if you need someplace to start. 
However, you can use the Library addon and [snap to closest face](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/539/snap-object-on-top-of-surface-of-other-object), to get alot of what you probably want already.

not really any point in re-inventing the wheel. Then, decide what features are missing that you want to add or improve from that point. 
The project would be more feasible that way.

Comment: besides this he refers to creating a scenario editor, within the game engine, that works as part of his game, what you describe is the most obvious part of doing things in Blender, your answer should be more a comment than a answer